# Why does Mongoose change order of fields on insert and what are other changes done to the data behind the scene?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've noticed that on insert of data into MonogDB manually, the order of the fields are maintained however, when done using Mongoose, it changes the order of the fields.

Why does this happen?

It also adds `_id` fields to nested objects or objects inside a field value.
It also adds a `_v` field to the document, (AFAIK) Mongoose uses it to maintain the version of the document.

Apart from this what all changes does Mongoose do behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Why does this happen?

- It is dependent on your schema and not the object when you are inserting it.

It also adds _id fields to nested objects or objects inside a field value?

This is Mongodb's doing, it is like inherent primary key, you can change the field name if you want to use it

You already know about _v I guess. But still, it remains unchanged as far as I know in most cases. Some interdependent changes would only cause change in it. This configurable as well btw.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why does the field change its position even when the oder in the Schema as well as the data passed is different? The `_id` added to the child object does not happen when manually inserted via MongoDB it happens only when you use Mongoose. I agree to the `_v` information.